# How to handle Lucene Hard Limit?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-configuration

I just found out that 2 billion documents are the Lucene hard limit.

So how can I handle when document count hits the limit? Is there is any way to automate from logstash?

Answer (score 1):

2B documents is a hard limit in Lucene, indeed. However, in Elasticsearch, since each shard is a full-fledge Lucene search engine, that means you get to store 2B document **per (primary) shard**.

So an easy way to lift that limit is to make sure that your index contains enough shards to hold all your documents. And if that's not enough because you don't know how many documents you will create (often the case with time-series data), then you can set up time-based indices and have a new index (with N primary shards) be create every day/week/month. That would make that 2B docs limits irrelevant.